# django model relationship with rest api

Tags: python, django, api

**Description**
the hospital is the user, a patient belongs to an hospital and a patient as an object has a card and diagnoses.
I dont know whats wrong maybe its the relationship, i dont known. i need help

**Error message**
TypeError at /patient/diagnoses
Got a `TypeError` when calling `Diagnoses.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `Diagnoses.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the `PatientsDiagnosesSerializer.create()` method to handle this correctly.
Original exception was:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 948, in create
    instance = ModelClass._default_manager.create(**validated_data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 431, in create
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 500, in __init__
    raise TypeError("%s() got an unexpected keyword argument '%s'" % (cls.__name__, kwarg))
TypeError: Diagnoses() got an unexpected keyword argument 'owner'
```

**urls.py of patient app**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PatientListAPIView.as_view(), name="patient"),
    path('<int:id>', views.PatientDetailAPIView.as_view(), name="patient"),
    path('card', views.PatientCardListAPIView.as_view(), name="card"),
    path('card/<int:id>', views.PatientCardDetailAPIView.as_view(), name="card"),
    path('diagnoses', views.PatientDiagnosesListAPIView.as_view(), name="diagnoses"),
    path('diagnoses/<int:id>', views.PatientDiagnosesDetailAPIView.as_view(), name="diagnoses")

]
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Patient, Card, Diagnoses


class PatientsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):   
    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'phone', 'email', 'state','country']

class PatientsCardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):  
    class Meta:
        model = Card
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'card_number']

class PatientsDiagnosesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    class Meta:
        model = Diagnoses
        fields = ['id', 'sickness', 'note']
```

**views.py of patient app**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.generics import ListCreateAPIView, RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView
from .serializers import PatientsSerializer, PatientsCardSerializer, PatientsDiagnosesSerializer
from .models import Patient
from rest_framework import permissions
from .permissions import IsOwner


# Patient Views
class PatientListAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = PatientsSerializer
    queryset = Patient.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsOwner,) 
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        return serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(owner=self.request.user)

class PatientDetailAPIView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = PatientsSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsOwner,)
    queryset = Patient.objects.all()
    lookup_field = "id"
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(owner=self.request.user)


class PatientCardListAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = PatientsCardSerializer
    queryset = Patient.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,) 
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        return serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(owner=self.request.user)

class PatientCardDetailAPIView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = PatientsCardSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsOwner,)
    queryset = Patient.objects.all()
    lookup_field = "id"
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(owner=self.request.user)



class PatientDiagnosesListAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = PatientsDiagnosesSerializer
    queryset = Patient.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,) 
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        return serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(owner=self.request.user)

class PatientDiagnosesDetailAPIView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = PatientsDiagnosesSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsOwner,)
    queryset = Patient.objects.all()
    lookup_field = "id"
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(owner=self.request.user)
```

**models.py of patient app**

```
from django.db import models
from authentication.models import User
# Create your models here.

class Patient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(to=User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Card(models.Model):    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    card_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    patient = models.OneToOneField(Patient, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return (self.patient.name)+"'s card"



class Diagnoses(models.Model):
    sickness = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    note = models.TextField(max_length=255, null=True)   
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.patient.name)+"'s diagnoses"
```

Comment: to get this error, which endpoint are you hitting and how does the payload look like?

Comment: i get the error when using POST to create new card and also same thing for diagnoses. Although the GET method works fine

Comment: Am trying to POST to the Card and Diagnoses endpoint

Answer (score 0):

> i get the error when using POST to create new card and also same thing for diagnoses

so it's this route, right?

```
path('card', views.PatientCardListAPIView.as_view(), name="card")
```

the view looks like this:

```
class PatientCardListAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = PatientsCardSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        return serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

in `perform_create()` you're calling `serializer.save()` with parameter `owner`, but your `serializer_class` (`PatientsCardSerializer`) has `model = Card`, but that model does not have `owner` column:

```
class PatientsCardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):  
    class Meta:
        model = Card
```

so you either dont mean to use the `owner` parameter in `serializer.save()`, or you are using wrong `serializer_class` in the view

Comment: i corrected that after a posted the question here. here is a link to the updated question. with the new errors am getting  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63770806/how-to-fix-django-model-instance