# how to fix django Model instance

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

**error messages**
ValueError: Cannot assign "<User: user0@example.com>": "Diagnoses.owner" must be a "Patient" instance

i get the above error when i try to create either a new card or diagnoses.
The card and diagnoses are meant to be an instance of the patient, just like the way a patient has a card and also diagnoses. The patient class has a foregin key referencing the User.
Here is the code

**views.py**

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.generics import ListCreateAPIView, RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView
from .serializers import PatientsSerializer, PatientsCardSerializer, PatientsDiagnosesSerializer
from .models import Patient, Card, Diagnoses
from rest_framework import permissions
from .permissions import IsOwner


# Patient Views
class PatientListAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = PatientsSerializer
    queryset = Patient.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsOwner,) 
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        return serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(owner=self.request.user)

class PatientDetailAPIView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = PatientsSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsOwner,)
    queryset = Patient.objects.all()
    lookup_field = "id"
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(owner=self.request.user)


class PatientCardListAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = PatientsCardSerializer
    queryset = Card.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,) 
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        return serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(owner=self.request.user)

class PatientCardDetailAPIView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = PatientsCardSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsOwner,)
    queryset = Card.objects.all()
    lookup_field = "id"
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(owner=self.request.user)



class PatientDiagnosesListAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = PatientsDiagnosesSerializer
    queryset = Diagnoses.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,) 
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        return serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(owner=self.request.user)

class PatientDiagnosesDetailAPIView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = PatientsDiagnosesSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsOwner,)
    queryset = Diagnoses.objects.all()
    lookup_field = "id"
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(owner=self.request.user)
```

**Models.py**

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(to=User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
class Card(models.Model):    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    card_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)    
    owner = models.OneToOneField(Patient, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return (self.patient.name)+"'s card"
   
class Diagnoses(models.Model):
    sickness = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    note = models.TextField(max_length=255, null=True)   
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Patient, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    def __str__(self):
        return (self.patient.name)+"'s diagnoses"
```

Comment: Show us the code you use to create an instance. There's no problem with the models. It's on execution that should be the problem.

Comment: Have added the code that is suppose to create the instance. i edited the post and added views.py

Comment: I have a few questions, 1.) Is the traceback leads to `views.py`??? 2.) Also, `User` is not `Patience`, so you can't just rely on the `User` instance unless `User` has a cross-reference to `Patience`. If there's cross-reference, we could resolve it by redirecting it to that object. If you only have one-way reference, I suggest querying that object `User` to `Patience`. I could answer but let's see what would be your move.

Comment: here is the Patient model

Comment: help check the Patient model, it references the User model. owner = models.ForeignKey(to=User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Comment: Any solution, am open to

Comment: I already saw that, what I meant is this `return serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)`. `self.request.user` is not a `Patient` Object. It's a user object. it emits error because of that. What I suggest is to query this `User` object to the `Patient` object. I might put this answer with additional context just in case.

Comment: I understand you now, waiting for your solution

Answer (score 1):

So far, `self.request.user` is a `User` Object. You cannot save it to the API or save to the model because of that. And for clarity, it's not a `Patient` Object.

Based on your situation, I would queue the `Patient` object with the `User` object (if this was a one-way reference object), and put that in the argument and do the save() method.

```py
class PatientCardListAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = PatientsCardSerializer
    queryset = Card.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,) 

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        getPatientFromUser = Patient.objects.get(owner=self.request.user)
        # getPatientFromUser returns `Patient` Instance. So you could bind it in `Card` Model.
        return serializer.save(owner=getPatientFromUser)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(owner=self.request.user)
```

Notes:

1. This is a solution for a one-way reference. (`User` being referred to as `Patient`)
2. If you have a cross-reference relationship between `User` and `Patience` (where User and Patience has a ForeignKey on each other), then declare your `User` Model.
3. The solution queries the Patient from User. As User is incompatible with that Foreign Object.

Comment: Sorry, how do i declare the User model for option 2

Comment: Oh, I thought you explicitly declared `User`, I guess one-way reference is your option for now.

Comment: You could declare your `User` Class with Subclass `AbstractBaseUser` or `AbstractUser`. But this requires re-declaration of User fields. Meaning it will be more customizable but you have to declare your fields on your own. Check the documentation about those classes for more information

Comment: If you don't intend to change your `User` Model for now, then I suggest going for the one-way reference solution that I provided from the above. (And if this seem enough, please mark it as accepted answer)

Comment: When i treid the first option you gave here is the error MultipleObjectsReturned at /patient/card
get() returned more than one Patient -- it returned 3!

Comment: Am using the custom user model for authentication using the AbstractBaseUser and BaseUserManager

Comment: This is a unique error. Shouldn't it be only one user per card? It seemed that multiple users have that card. And you declared it as `OneToOneField`. Sorry, quite confused.

Comment: And i can successfully create the card and diagnoses and assign to a patient  using django admin

Comment: You have to understand that `django-admin` implicitly gives the right object for you to connect. While in APIs / in the codebase, you should have determined the right object to explicitly bind to. Which is what we're doing right now. I suggest try having at least one user per card. And try the method I suggested again.